# Is there a way to wrap plot titles in ggarrange?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm trying to visualize where in the country students typically come from, depending on program. Since the bar chart will need to have a different order for each program, I've chosen to generate graphs separately and display them via ggarrange, as follows:

[image]

As you can see the plot titles get truncated. Is there a way around this?

I'm using the following code:

```
antal_hemvist_program<-function(x){totdata%>%filter(program==x)%>%ggplot(aes(x=fct_rev(fct_infreq(NYA_REGION))))+
geom_bar()+
theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_text(size=5))+ylab("Antal")+
coord_flip()+ggtitle(x)}

hv_n_program<-lapply(unique(totdata$program),antal_hemvist_program)

ggarrange(plotlist=hv_n_program)
```

Small excerpt of data:

```
structure(list(program = c("IPPE", "Ekonom", "IPPE", "Magister_FEK", 
"Systemvetenskap", "Magister_FIN", "Ekonom", "Webmaster", "Maklarekonom", 
"Maklarekonom", "IPPE", "Animation", "Magister_FEK", "Maklarekonom", 
"IPPE", "IPPE", "IPPE", "IPPE", "Webmaster", "Systemvetenskap", 
"Digitala_Medier", "Maklarekonom", "Magister_FEK", "Digitala_Medier", 
"Ekonom", "IPPE", "Systemvetenskap", "Maklarekonom", "Systemvetenskap", 
"IPPE", "Animation", "Maklarekonom", "IPPE", "Systemvetenskap", 
"Personalekonomi", "Ekonom", "Personalekonomi", "Webmaster", 
"Ekonom", "IPPE", "IPPE", "IPPE", "Personalekonomi", "Systemvetenskap", 
"Personalekonomi", "Animation", "Digitala_Medier", "IPPE", "Ekonom", 
"Maklarekonom"), NYA_REGION = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
9L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 8L), .Label = c("UTANFÖR SVERIGE", 
"ÖVRIGA LANDET", "STORGÖTEBORG", "oklart", "SÖDRA BOHUSLÄN", 
"UDDEVALLA", "VÄSTERGÖTLAND", "VÄNERSBORG", "TROLLHÄTTAN", "NORRA BOHUSLÄN", 
"DALSLAND"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `plot.title.position = 'plot'` to your call to theme, which will align titles and subtitles with the entire plot rather than the title panels.

```r
antal_hemvist_program <- function(x {
  totdata %>%
  filter(program==x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=fct_rev(fct_infreq(NYA_REGION)))) +
    geom_bar() +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
          axis.text.x=element_text(size=5),
          plot.title.position = 'plot') +
    ylab("Antal")+
    coord_flip()+ggtitle(x)}
```

[image]

Comment: @calldwellst It tells me that "'plot.title.position' is not a valid theme element name" ?

Comment: You may need to update your `ggplot2` installation.